# Need help formulating a query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model named Portfolios, where one field contains a set of Widgets. I am trying to create a query that will return me the Unique set of Widgets from a selected set of Portfolios.

```
list(Portfolio.objects.filter(user=user).values('widgets').distinct())
```

From this query, I am getting back a list that looks like this

```
[{'widgets': 2}, {'widgets': 6}, {'widgets': 159}, {'widgets': 184}, {'widgets': 291}]
```

What I can't figure out is how to have it return the list of the resolved Widget instances. Ultimately, what I need, is this.

```
[WidgetInst1, WidgetInst2, WidgetInst3, WidgetInst4, WidgetInst5]
```

I can of course pull the instances out of the dictionary entries if they have to come back that way. I am trying to do this with the best performance possible, since I am trying to resolve performance issues from manually iterating over results and doing additionally queries.

In addition to the list of Widgets, I also need to get the list of all of the Portfolios that the Widgets are contained in. What would be the best way to go about that from a performance stand point? Do I need to iterate over each of the Widgets and do a separate query for each one?

```
class Portfolio(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    widgets = models.ManyToManyField(Widget, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your models? What is the `Portfolio.widgets` field?

Comment: How will you be displaying the `Portfolio` and `Widgets`? Can you share the relevant part of your template where you are rendering them?

Comment: I added the code to the post. This is not for display. I am not developing the UI. I am using the results to do some back end processing in order to produce a Rest JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `Widget` model directly and get your 2 object lists in 2 queries

```
widgets = Widget.objects.filter(portfolio__user=user).distinct()
portfolios = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: The first one is exactly what I needed. I still haven't gotten my head around the fact that there are always reverse relationships with the Django models. Still think one directional.

For the second one, it is a bit more complex. I basically need to end up with a dictionary where the 'widget' is the key, and each has a set of values that are all of the Portfolios they belong to.

For example,
```
[
{ Widget10: [Port1, Port12, Port32]},
{ Widget19: [Port7, Port32, Port19]}
]
```